# Regex on numbers and spaces

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match numbers surrounded by spaces, like this string:
" 1 2 3 "

I'm puzzled why the regex `\s[0-9]\s` matches 1 and 3 but not 2. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the space has already been consumed:

```
\s[0-9]\s
```

This matches "spacedigitspace" so lets go through the process

```
" 1 2 3 "

 ^
 |
```

No match

```
" 1 2 3 "

  ^
  |
```

No match

```
" 1 2 3 "

   ^
   |
```

Matches, consume " 1 "

```
"2 3 "

 ^
 |
```

No match

```
"2 3 "

  ^
  |
```

No match

```
"2 3 "

   ^
   |
```

No match

```
"2 3 "

    ^
    |
```

Matches, consume " 3 "

You want a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\s)\d(?=\s)
```

This is very different, as it look for `\d` and then *asserts* that it is preceded by, and followed by, a space.  This assertion is "zero width" which means that the spaces aren't consumed by the engine.

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, the regex `\s[0-9]\s` does not match `2` only when you go through all matches in the string `" 1 2 3 "` one by one. If you were to try to start matching at positions 1 or 2, `" 2 "` would be matched.

The reason for this is that `\s` is capturing part of the input - namely, the spaces around the digit. When you match `" 1 "`, the space between `1` and `2` is already taken; the regex engine is looking at the tail of the string, which is `"2 3 "`. At this point, there is no space in front of `2` that the engine could capture, so it goes straight to finding `" 3 "`

To fix this, put spaces into zero-length [*look-arounds*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), like this:

```
(?<=\s)[0-9](?=\s)
```

Now the engine ensures that there are spaces in front and behind the digit without *consuming* these spaces as part of the match. This lets the engine treat the space between `1` and `2` as a space behind `1` and also as a space in front of `2`, thus returning both matches.

Answer (score 0):

The input is captured, and the subsequent matches won't match, you can use a lookahead to fix this

```
\s+\d+(?=\s+)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `\s[0-9]\s` mathces `" 1 "` and `" 3 "`. As the space after the `1` is matched, it can't also be used to match `" 2 "`.

You can use a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead to match digits that are surrounded by spaces:

```
(?<= )(\d+)(?= )
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hT1dT6/1